# Proof $\tbinom{n}{2}=\tbinom{k}{2}+k(n-k)+\tbinom{n-k}{2}$ based on binomial coefficient definition

Tags: combinations, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

How can I prove this equation using the binomial coefficient definition?

$\tbinom{n}{2}=\tbinom{k}{2}+k(n-k)+\tbinom{n-k}{2},     1\le k\le n$

So far I've just written the equation using the definition. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Try expressing $\binom{k}{2}$ as $\frac{k!}{2!(k - 2)!}$.  Write expressions for the other binomial coefficients, then show that $\binom{k}{2} + k(n - k) + \binom{n- k}{2}$ simplifies to $\binom{n}{2}$.

Comment: Suppose we have $n$ people... $k$ of which are men and the remaining $(n-k)$ of which are women.  How many ways can we pick two people?  If we counted directly?  If we broke into cases based on the number of men selected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [${n\choose 2} - {k\choose 2} = {n-k\choose 2} +k(n-k)$ Marked box or unmarked box](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536143/n-choose-2-k-choose-2-n-k-choose-2-kn-k-marked-box-or-unmarked-bo)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Fix $k$ and label the $n$ elements as $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. There are 3 kinds of 2-element subsets from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$:

- Both elements are from $\{1,\ldots,k\}$
- 1 element is from $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and the other element is from $\{k+1,\ldots,n\}$
- Both elements are from $\{k+1,\ldots,n\}$

Can you compute: how many subsets there are for each of the 3 kinds above?